# Lowest note on piano : A0 or A-1?

Tags: piano, digital-piano

I am confused. I have bought a digital piano (a Yamaha Clavinova CLP-735) and I saw this :

[image]

So they say the lowest note on the piano is A-1.

However, on the musical apps that I use on my phone, they refer to the lowest note on the piano as A0. Obviously, this shifts all numbers by 1.

It seems unlikely the manual for the digital piano is wrong, as they clearly know how music works?

So which one is wrong? Or can both be correct, and both conventions exist? If so, is there a context that helps decide which of the 2 conventions is the appropriate one?

Comment: Also see [scientific pitch notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation)

Comment: They know how music works; they also know that putting numbers to octaves is completely arbitrary.  I imagine there's a historical reason for their using a standard different from the more common one, and that the reason probably has something to do with 61-key instruments, where the lowest key is C2 in scientific pitch notation; Yamaha probably called that key "C1" at some early time and the name has stuck.